# Why does insertInto fail with "assertion failed: No plan for InsertIntoTable"?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using SparkSql for querying. I'm trying something like:

```
val sqc = new SQLContext(sc);
import sqc.createSchemaRDD

var p1 = Person("Hari",22)
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(p1))    
rdd1.registerAsTable("data")

var p2 = Person("sagar", 22)
var rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Array(p2))
rdd2.insertInto("data")
```

but getting the error

> "java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for
>   InsertIntoTable Map(), false"

Seems I'm using the insertInto the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the error for normal SchemaRDD. When I tried `insertInto` with a SchemaRDD backed by a Parquet file, it succeeded. It looks only Parquet-backed tables are supported for insertInto method.

The [1.1.0 API documentation on SQLContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html) tells that tables from Parquet File can be used for insertInto operations. > "This registered table can be used as the target of future insertInto operations."